# Relational database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables set up in phpmyadmin- table userid and table data. The userid table has a single column `userid` which is the primary key. The table data has `id|name|src|` and a bunch of other information. The issue right now is that the column id which is a 16 character long string acts as a primary key in table userid and foreign key in table data. Now if the same user wants to upload more than one image then i am having to repeat the id in the table data and the table is becoming very large. Is there any other way to go about this(i am relatively new so im sorry if this sound rather stupid.). Finally is there actually any performance boost in this situation by indexing the id of the user in the other table as to me it seems like just a waste of space as im haveing to repeat the user id one more time in the table userid as compared to having a single table to hold both data and user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case with One to Many Relations. I don't think that the table will grow that large to give you issues. This would be the way to go.

Alternatively, a strategy used by many cms and platforms to store settings. You can store JSON object having src of image into the image column. But this will add the overhead of updating image information every time a image created and deleted.

Comment: So is it better to index it or just use a single table

Comment: I would say it is the way to go. I am not aware of other methods that will cut down the overheads.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. You will have to repeat the userid otherwise you won't know who it belongs to.

Comment: So indexing is not necessary. I can just have a single table with id|name|src|data....... and improve the performance

Comment: Pretty much if this is all your handling.